# Do accidentals take precedence over the key signature? I've included an example of a measure for a clarinet in Bb

Tags: notation

[image]
A measure written for Bb clarinet.

Comment: Short answer: yes, that's the whole point of accidentals. The written alteration is the actual note to be played, overriding and completely ignoring key signature for the rest of the bar, so the lower D and F are *natural* D and F, the upper C, D, F and G are all flats. The transposition doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  An accidental is taken at face value, regardless of the key signature.   It isn't additive.  If you see B♭ you play B♭, whatever the key signature.